# Replace a part of a string with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a with location:

`/Users/spotter/Downloads`

and within the Downloads folder there are two files:

`test1.txt` and `test2.txt`.

I want to write a shell script to save all the files to a list with a line like this:

`file_list="$(ls /Users/spotter/Downloads)"`

and `echo $file_list` will return:

`/Users/spotter/Downloads/test1.txt`
`/Users/spotter/Downloads/test2.txt`

However I want to change part of the dirname. Particularly I want to change the `/Users/spotter` part to `gs://my_bucket`

I tried this like so:

`file_list="$(ls /Users/spotter/Downloads |
while read path; do dirname "$path" | sed -i "s|/Users/spotter|gs://my_bucket|g"; done)"`

which returns:

`sed: no input files`

when I do `echo $file_list` I want this to be the output:

`gs://my_bucket/Downloads/test1.txt`

`gs://my_bucket/Downloads/test2.txt`

EDIT:

I MUST use `ls` and I need to keep the entire string replacement within the single list at the end somehow or another.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I could be wrong but part of the reason I am using ls is because my files are actually on a google server and I only know how to list them with `ls`.

Comment: You don't really need sed for that. You can just use Bash string manipulation for this.
`for FILE in $FILE_LIST; do echo ${FILE/\/Users\/spotter/gs:\/\/mybucket}; done`
gives:
`gs://mybucket/Downloads/test1.txt`
`gs://mybucket/Downloads/test2.txt`

 (More info at: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/ )

Comment: I do need to stick with ls, and I also want to keep the entire output as as one list instead of a loop through after creating the list. I will edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU find:

```
file_list=$(find /Users/spotter/Downloads/ -type f -printf 'gs://my_bucket/Downloads/%f\n')
```

or only with bash:

```
cd /Users/spotter/Downloads/
file_list=$(for i in *.txt; do echo "gs://my_bucket/Downloads/$i"; done)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can move from ls to find and want to stick with sed:

```
file_list=$(find /Users/spotter/Downloads -type f | sed 's|/Users/spotter/|gs://my_bucket/|g')
```